# comparison of two probability measures

Tags: probability-theory

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two probability measures on some measurable space $(S,\Sigma)$.

Assume that $\Sigma=\sigma(\Pi)$, where $\Pi$ is a pi-system.

Then, I know that if $P=Q$ on $\Pi$, then $P=Q$ on $\Sigma$, but I am wondering whether this result can be generalized in the following sense.

> If $P(A)\geq Q(A)$ for every $A \in \Pi$, then can we say that $P(A)\geq Q(A)$ for every $A \in \Sigma$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true. Consider the following example:
$$S = \{0, 1, 2\}, \, \Sigma = \{\text{all subsets of } S\}, \, \Pi = \{\varnothing, \{0\}, \{1\}\}.$$
Define two probability measures on $\Sigma$ by 
\begin{align}
& P(\{0\}) = P(\{1\}) = \frac{1}{2}, P(\{2\}) = 0; \\
& Q(\{0\}) = Q(\{1\}) = Q(\{2\}) = \frac{1}{3}.
\end{align}
Clearly, for every $A \in \Pi$, $P(A) \geq Q(A)$. While for $A = \{0, 2\} \in \Sigma = \sigma(\Pi)$, we have
$$P(A) = \frac{1}{2} < Q(A) = \frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: It is clear that the class of events $A$ for which $P(A)\ge Q(A)$ is a monotone class. Thus, if $\Pi$ were an *algebra*  then the inequality would hold on all of $\Sigma$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Indeed.